# Is the intersection of ultraconnected components relatively open?

Tags: general-topology

A topological space is [*ultraconnected*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraconnected_space), if every two non-empty closed subsets intersect. An *ultraconnected component* of a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is a maximal ultraconnected subset. Let us abbreviate an ultraconnected component as an *ultracomponent*.

#### Problem

Let $C, D \subset X$ be ultracomponents of $(X, \mathcal{T})$.

Is $C \cap D \in \mathcal{T}|D$ ?

Here $\mathcal{T}|D$ is the subspace topology on $D$.

#### Background

- If $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is [finitely generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology), then ultracomponents are open.
- In general, an ultracomponent is not open. For example, the ultracomponents of $(\mathbb{Q}, \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}|\mathbb{Q})$ are the singletons which are closed, but not open.
- In general, an ultracomponent is not closed. For example, the [particular point topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology) (with at least 3 points) has ultracomponents which are open (since it is finitely generated), but not closed.
- Ultraconnected space may not be finitely generated. For example, [integer broom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_broom_topology) is such a space.